# Find a minimal spanning set of vectors for the row space of A.

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a minimal spanning set of vectors for the row space of A.

Matrix $A$
$\begin{bmatrix}
2&4&6&4  
\\2&5&7&6   
\\2&3&5&2 
\end{bmatrix}$

I believe to solve this problem I need to preform elementary row operations to the reduced row echelon for. So I have reduced my matrix to

$\begin{bmatrix}
1&2&3&2  
\\0&1&1&2  
\\0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$

However I am not sure if I should multiply row 1 by 1/2 or not. If I did not I would get

$\begin{bmatrix}
2&4&6&4  
\\0&1&1&2  
\\0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$

So here my solution would be. A minimal spanning set for row(A) is the vectors [2 4 6 4] and [0 1 1 2] or should it be [1 2 3 2] and [0 1 1 2]

Comment: Either is correct.

Comment: so reduced row echelon form doesn't need leading 1's in each row?

Comment: The definition of RREF specifies leading $1$'s in each row, but as far as a *spanning set* is concerned, notice, for example, that the pair of vectors $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ and the pair of vectors $(2, 0)$ and $(0, 2)$ will both span $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: okay so leading 1s is not a concern in spanning sets but you still need to get it in descending form on the diagonal

Comment: Backing up to the title question, a minimal spanning set for the rowspace is a *basis* for the rowspace.  A row echelon form gives one (as does the reduced row echelon form), but these are not the only ways a basis can be constructed.